# What do you call a "community - manager"?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

What terms are there to describe people who act as **representers**, managers and organizers **of social communities**? In a way that they connect people with each other, but also organize activities etc. for the community - i.e "manage" the group?

It would be great if there were any (also creative!) suggestions for catchy words to describe that role!

**The context:**
We are developing a web application, more specifically a European-wide social community platform to connect refugees and local supporters and provide them with several tools to overcome (some of their) obstacles.

This platform will be partly divided into local communities that are to a large extent managed by volunteers from each community. That means they would be administrators of the online presence of that community, but also regularly organize offline events and activities, organize hackathons, etc.

The word I am looking for would be their "job title". In the early planning stage, we used to call them "Ambassadors", however recently decided that that is too "businessy".

Comment: My own personal coinage would be *social convenor*. I can't think of anything better.  However, bear in mind that in Britain a Convenor is specifically a trade union official.

Comment: Here on StackExhange they are quite literally called *community managers*. But in more journalistic, scholastic, and diplomatic contexts I've seen *community organizers* and *local leaders*. When companies are trying to motivate or inspire individuals to take up this mantle, they'll sometimes use a more highfalutin title in a similar vein. I remember once in the early 2000s, the company which makes he Opera browser set up such a program and nominated local Opera *ambassadors*.

Comment: If elected, these people are called *government*.

Comment: I need more context and a sample sentence, and have voted to close.  If you're talking about a google group, you could say *moderator*.

Comment: @aparente001 I edited the question and hope it provides enough context now

Comment: How about "community leaders"?

Comment: "Goði" is *perfect* for this. They were elected (or somehow wrested, but still required popular support) adjudicators and cat wranglers by definition.

Comment: I think "director" is the most common term in the US, for someone who is paid to manage the activities of a social group.

Answer (score 1):

The term "community organizer", although not creative, may be descriptive and understandable to the people who need the community's help.

[Here's a Wikipedia page on community organizing.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_organizing)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft and others in the tech community use the term [**evangelist**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alowe/2004/02/07/what-is-an-evangelist-developer-evangelist-in-my-case/).

The job entails (taken from the link):

> Here are some of the activities that make up my job (there are many other things I do on a daily basis but this is a good snapshot):
>
> - Presenting/Training .NET development topics for customers
> - Working with User Groups to ensure they get adequate support from Microsoft
> - Writing sample code for customers
> - Working with local influentials such as MVPs and RD to ensure they have what they need to be great customer evangelists
> - Organizing and managing local developer events such as DevDays
> - The most important part of my job, IMHO, is to collect developer feedback on all things related to software development on the Microsoft platform.

Comment: It really abuses the term, though. You better have a **really** good product or you're not really preaching such good news. You are correct that MS uses it in exactly this manner, though. No argument on that point.